# How does protocol extension work in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, nsobject, swift-protocols

I am starting a new iOS `Swift` project. I need to add some functionality that all of the project classes should inherit. Unlike `Objective C` not all classes in `Swift` are inherited from any particular class i.e. `NSObject`. For example,

I cannot create extension of `Any` or `AnyObject` class, like I can for `NSObject`. For example, below code is OK.

```
extension NSObject {

    @objc var classTag: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

But, extension on `AnyObject` give compiler error,

> Non-nominal type 'AnyObject' cannot be extended

So, I have decided to make all swift classes in my project to inherit from my `BaseClass` which is actually inherited from `NSObject`.

```
class BaseClass: NSObject {

    @objc var classTag: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

And other classes i.e.

```
class OtherClass: BaseClass {
    // have classTag
}
```

Before I make a policy for my team, to inherit all classes from `BaseClass`, I want to know if there are some disadvantages of inheriting all the classes from `NSObject` by default.

Comment: You should use protocols and structures instead

Comment: If you are programming in Swift I see absolutely no reason for any class to inherit from NSObject unless there is some special dependency that requires it. And why even lock your design into having one superclass for all classes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As I said I might need to impose some common functionality of my project classes. classTag is just an example. Even might be for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is even a need to inherit from `NSObject` if you are making a `BaseClass` to be inherited by other classes.

You can simply add `classTag` in the `BaseClass` itself, i.e.

```
class BaseClass {
    var classTag: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    func someFunc() {
        print(self.classTag)
    }
}
```

Another option can be to use `protocol` and `protocol extension` and provide the default definition of `classTag`, i.e.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var classTag: String { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    var classTag: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Then, you can conform `SomeProtocol` to the classes wherever required, i.e.

```
class SubClass: SomeProtocol {
    func someFunc() {
        print(self.classTag)
    }
}
```

In any case, inheriting from `NSObject` is unnecessary since you don't need any `NSObject` specific functionality for that.

Comment: For protocol all the subclasses need to implement the someFunc() right? But I can reduce some of their tasks by default function in base class?

Comment: No they won't. That's what the protocol extension is for.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan you should prefer using a struct over a class. Use classes only if you need to create a shared instance (singleton) or if you need to subclass an existing class.

Answer (score 3):

- Classes inherited from NSObject cannot be `final`. While whole module optimization turned on, Swift will add final when possible but not in objective c classes. This is micro optimization and I really won't consider unless you have really special case.
- When considering using copy semantics (using structs) you will not be able to extend your structs by inheritance.
- You will add much noise in auto complete in IDE.
- Using protocols (POP) can give you more flexibility/power. Like conditional conformance etc... And you can extend NSObject if needed.

Consider using `protocol extension` and maybe structs instead of `NSObject`.

```
protocol Base {
  func work()
}

extension Base {
  func work() {...}
}

struct AppState: Base {}

AppState().work()
```